# Package maven artifacts from local repository

Tags: maven

I'm aware of artifactory (which is planned in the future), but it's requested to package the artifacts on our releases.
We currently do on a script:

```
printf "\nCopying artifacts...\n"
for artifact_dir in "$HOME"/.m2/repository/com/foo/{*-ear,*-ui,*-tool}; do
  highest_version=$(find "${artifact_dir}"/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n" | sort -V | tail -1)
  artifact_name=$(basename "${artifact_dir}")
  mkdir --parent "${artifacts_out}/com/foo/${artifact_name}/${highest_version}"
  cp --archive "${artifact_dir}/${highest_version}"/* \
               "${artifacts_out}/com/foo/${artifact_name}/${highest_version}"
done
```

But as you can see it's not very neat, p.e we can not create a release with older artifacts because the script always takes the newest one.

Is there a maven plugin or something that permits to archive specific artifacts ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create bundles of artifacts, run the Maven assembly plugin during the build. It can be used to gather artifacts, zip them and deploy the result to Artifactory/Nexus.

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies.html is a good read. Although I don't see my user case, because I'm trying to replicate the folder structure of the maven repository.

Comment: @anat0lius Why do you care about the folder structure?

Comment: Requirements :( External scripts needs that structure in order they can work. The real solution would be artifactory...